# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, jsf, garbage-collection, richfaces

How can I prevent this?

```
Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

It's happening for example if I reloading datatable page often. I understand it that there is something wrong set with garbage collector..

I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE, JSF2, richfaces4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is specific to Tomcat. It's pretty a poor hotpublisher/hotdeployer and it suffers from memory leaks. I'd suggest to turn off autopublishing by the server configuration screen in Eclipse and just manually restart Tomcat whenever you want to reflect the saved changes. Restarting shouldn't take much time anyway if you have only one project.

Glassfish, for example, is much more robust (and faster!) when it comes to hotpublishing. As to how to install Glassfish and integrate it in Eclipse for JSF 2.0 development, check [this tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html).

Comment: Aha, I see the difference. If auto publishing is on, changes in xhtml take effect without restarting of server. If is it off, changes in xhtml are not reflected, until server is restarted. So it's the sophie's choice :-) I'll take a look at the glassfish server, thank you again!

Comment: I think that modern Tomcat 7/8/9 is no longer a reason for  `OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` itself. `<Context         reloadable="true">` make development much pleasant if application have no memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate more space to the PermGenSpace of the tomcat JVM.

This can be done with the JVM argument : `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m`

By default, the PermGen space is 64M (and it contains all compiled classes, so if you have a lot of jar (classes) in your classpath, you may indeed fill this space).

On a side note, you can monitor the size of the PermGen space with [JVisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) and you can even inspect its content with [YourKit Java Profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/)

Answer (score -1):

If you have more number of projects in your webapps folder this exception will come .Remove some projects this exception will not come.